# Problem filling out ESTA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, mexico, italian-citizens

I'm Italian & I need some information.
I'm filling out the ESTA and one of the questions is:

> Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country?

I don't know what to answer because my trip plan will be to stay in California for a month and then go to Mexico by land.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question is clear, your stay is as a tourist, your onward travel is not the reason you visit the USA.